# Google Drive comment API rectangle tagging

Tags: google-drive-api, google-drive-android-api, google-drive-realtime-api

I am trying to show squares on images using the Comment API, when I try to create the comment from the web interface of the drive and mark a region the square shows up, but when I try it using the API nothing is shown except a comment, there is no square which I provided as a rect to the API.

this is what I am trying to use as an anchor:

```
{'r': 'head', 'a': [{'rect': {'x': 0.0, 'y': 0.0, 'w': 100.0, 'h': 100.0, 'mw': 480.0, 'mh': 216.0}}]}"
```

but when I do so it doesn't work at all ?

after couple of painful hours and headaches I got to a clue where the anchor of the Web created comment is `[null,[null,[0.4425,0.225,0.60625,0.3716666666666667]]]` and the API created comment has the above mentioned anchor. can anyone help me with the problem ?

Comment: It's seeking debugging help but needs more information. The question should be updated to include desired behavior, a specific problem or error, and the shortest code necessary to reproduce the problem.

Comment: I am using the google API tester

Comment: In order to ask a question we need to see the code you are using to send the request.   We cant see that with the tester.   please edit your question and include the code that is being used to make the requests then explain the issues with it.

Comment: Can you specify to which type of document you want to append the comment? What do you mean with squares on images? Can you provide a screenshot of what the comment you want to create is supposed to look like?

Comment: I want to show a highlight on an image which can be done in the drive web interface easily using the comments feature, but with the API it doesnt do the same !

Comment: Here is an example of what I want to achieve using the google drive API https://i.ibb.co/9swKG87/Screenshot-20191210-165031.png

Answer (score 0):

### There seems to be a bug from Google's side

It has already been reported at [Public Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/146053105).

I suggest you to give it a "star" to increase visibility and hope that it will get fixed soon.